# Attach TProcess to a running process

Tags: freepascal

I want to read some info from a console process. I know how to do this by using `TProcess` to start the the process and read bytes through pipes, see [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#Reading_large_output).

Is this possible if the console process is already running? How do I attach `TProcess` to the handle of the console process?

Comment: No, it is not possible to redirect the output after a console app is already running, and `TProcess` is not designed to attach to an already running process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - OK, is there any other way of doing this that you are aware of, assuming I opened the console process with input & output pipes open as detached process, then closed my main program, and opened it again?

Comment: again, what you are asking for is not possible. You will have to find another solution. Like using OCR to scrape the console window for new text. Or using DLL injection to hook output functions such as `WriteConsoleOutput()`, `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()`, etc

Comment: the only other option I can think of is to have the main app launch a helper process that creates the pipes and launches the console app with them, and then uses IPC to communicate with the main app. That way, the main app can close and restart as many times as it wants while the helper keeps running to monitor the console output.

Comment: Thats clever! Actually the only part that is missing from my code is the IPC part, since I already use a worker thread to monitor the process. If you want turn your comment into an answer so i can accept it.